# Can't package BlackBerry WebWorks app

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I'm trying to enable Web Inspector to debug my WorkWorks app, but I need to package it first and the package command is not working.

I followed the instructions here: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v2_1/enabling_web_inspector.html

...but i'm getting an error that "bbwp" is not a recognized command. I think I'm in the wrong directory.

The documentation says to go to the "installation folder for the BlackBerry WebWorks Packager". Does anyone know what exactly is the correct directory?

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry 10 WebWork sdk provides web tool to package your application. If you select build and install with debug mode on, web inspector will automatically get invoked on application startup and if you select release mode than web inspector pop up will automatically vanish.

You can refer this link:

http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v2_2/creating_a_webworks_project.html#kba1393261047290